# Blender 2.83: When I move my object the force field effect does not move with the object

Tags: modeling

I created a space ship. I used particles and a force field to direct the engine exhaust. It looks perfect after running animation. It renders very well.

However, after the selection of all possible parts of the space ship including the force fields (Just did an A-key) when I move or rotate the space ship, the particle flow does not move with the space ship model but remains where it was originally.

How do I fix this? It has to be something simple I am missing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Calin De Beverly

Comment: The particles depend on the object/emitter they are generated on/from. I'd recommend to parent the emitter to the ship, the force field as well. Also i wonder what the screw modifier has to do with the situation?

Comment: I will try parenting. Why did you mention the screw modifier? I have not used one in my model.

Comment: Your question *had* the tag, i just had to be certain first.

Comment: did you end up finding a fix? I am trying to simulate dividing biological cells. Cells are moving due to forces between them. However, the force fields are fixed and would not follow the center of cells. I think it is a problem similar to what you are referring to above.